# Mercurial existing Active Directory integration failing for a new user

Tags: active-directory, iis, mercurial

We've got an existing Mercurial server running under Windows 2008/IIS that is using Active Directory for authentication.

We have three existing users that have no problems at all with Mercurial.  Clone/push/pull all work just fine.

I was trying to get another domain user set up with Mercurial this morning, and he can clone and pull, but push results with an 'authorization failed' message.  I have confirmed and re-confirmed his domain user name and password are correct.

Is there any special user permission/role I need to assign to Mercurial users?  My MercurialRepositories path on the server has 'Full Control' for all domain users, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Is there a list of configuration locations I should check?

I don't have `allow_push = *` set up in my server's configuration, but I haven't needed this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It started working after I included a list of explicit users in the server's hgrc file.

```
[web]
allow_push = jdoe, jsmith
```

I still am perplexed why it was working without an allow_push setting previously.

Comment: It is indeed strange that it worked before, without a `allow_push` setting. Mercurial compares the authenticated user with this list and wont allow anybody to push by default, like I [wrote about here](http://serverfault.com/a/343593/14103).