# How do I setup authentication with Mecurial 1.3.1 on Debian Lenny?

Tags: mercurial

I have been searching, but I couldn't find a tutorial with a step by step guide to creating authentication for Mercurial. From what I have found, a lot of people are pointing to this resource, but it doesn't seem to show what I am trying to achieve: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories

Can someone please show me where I can find a guide to setup authentication with Mercurial? HTTPS, or public key system, they both work!

Thank you

Comment: authentication heavy depends from access protocol. http OR ssh, you have to select

Comment: Lenny is End of Life.

Comment: @Zoredache Should I be upgrading to Squeeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you've found has the information for **HTTP**, it's in section [6.3: Adding authentication](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Adding_authentication). You need to configure Apache to do Basic authentication for requests to `hgwebdir.cgi`, that's all.

Just remember that [Mercurial **does not authenticate HTTP users**](https://serverfault.com/a/343593/14103). It's the job of the front-end webserver, such as Apache. That has the advantage that you can re-use your existing infrastructure for authentication: if you've already got a setup where Apache uses LDAP for Active Directory authentication, then Mercurial will inherit that.

For **SSH** you can look in [the Hg Book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html#sec:collab:ssh) and the [Shared SSH](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SharedSSH) and [Multiple Committers](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MultipleCommitters) wiki pages. Here you must remember that access control boils down to normal file system permissions once the user has been logged into the server.

Finally, I wrote a guide about [interacting with remote repositories](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/remote/) that might contain a hint or two that you can use.